# How can i set padding to BottomSheetScaffold in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I want to set the start and end padding to BottomSheetScaffold but as you can see, the borromsheet has extra color in the background and has not had good ui. How can i set padding to bottomsheet?

[image]

```
 BoxWithConstraints() {
            val maxHeight = maxHeight
            val sheetHeight = maxHeight / 4.dp
            BottomSheetScaffold(
                modifier = modifier
                    .statusBarsPadding()
                    .navigationBarsPadding(),
                scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
//                sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
                sheetContent = {
                   
                },
                sheetBackgroundColor = Color.Unspecified,
                sheetPeekHeight = 51.dp
            ) {
                Box(modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()) {
                    Column(modifier = modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()) {
                      
                        Box(modifier = modifier
                            .weight(1f)
                            .background(Color.Cyan)) {
                          
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue recently. I found that this issue is caused by the sheet elevation. By default, sheet elevation is 8dp. Make it 0dp which will make the issue to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the exact problem, but just in case, you need to move your  `Color.Cyan` to before the padding, and also to the Column, like this:

```
BottomSheetScaffold(
        sheetContent = {},
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 51.dp,
        sheetShape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Cyan)
            .padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Cyan)
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .weight(1f)
                ) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's not working. If you change one of the Color.Cyan to Color.Red you can see it's not working. I want to bottom sheet padding color to be transparent not exactly the same background color